# Unable to access Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a Kubernetes v1.3.3 cluster on CoreOS based on the [contrib repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ansible).  My cluster appears healthy, and I would like to use the Dashboard but I am unable to access the UI, even when all authentication is disabled.  Below are details of the `kubernetes-dashboard` components, as well as some API server configs/output.  What am I missing here?

**Dashboard Components**

```
core@ip-10-178-153-240 ~ $ kubectl get ep kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2016-07-28T23:40:57Z
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "345970"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kubernetes-dashboard
  uid: bb49360f-551c-11e6-be8c-02b43b6aa639
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 172.16.100.9
    targetRef:
      kind: Pod
      name: kubernetes-dashboard-v1.1.0-nog8g
      namespace: kube-system
      resourceVersion: "345969"
      uid: d4791722-5908-11e6-9697-02b43b6aa639
  ports:
  - port: 9090
    protocol: TCP

core@ip-10-178-153-240 ~ $ kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2016-07-28T23:40:57Z
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "109199"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
  uid: bb4804bd-551c-11e6-be8c-02b43b6aa639
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.20.164.194
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
core@ip-10-178-153-240 ~ $ kubectl describe svc/kubernetes-dashboard --

namespace=kube-system
Name:           kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:      kube-system
Labels:         k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
            kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true
Selector:       k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:           ClusterIP
IP:         172.20.164.194
Port:           <unset> 80/TCP
Endpoints:      172.16.100.9:9090
Session Affinity:   None
No events.

core@ip-10-178-153-240 ~ $ kubectl get po  kubernetes-dashboard-v1.1.0-nog8g --namespace=kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/created-by: |
      {"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicationController","namespace":"kube-system","name":"kubernetes-dashboard-v1.1.0","uid":"3a282a06-58c9-11e6-9ce6-02b43b6aa639","apiVersion":"v1","resourceVersion":"338823"}}
  creationTimestamp: 2016-08-02T23:28:34Z
  generateName: kubernetes-dashboard-v1.1.0-
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    version: v1.1.0
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-v1.1.0-nog8g
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "345969"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kubernetes-dashboard-v1.1.0-nog8g
  uid: d4791722-5908-11e6-9697-02b43b6aa639
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.1.0
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 9090
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 30
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9090
      protocol: TCP
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 50Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 50Mi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-lvmnw
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  nodeName: ip-10-178-153-57.us-west-2.compute.internal
  restartPolicy: Always
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-lvmnw
    secret:
      secretName: default-token-lvmnw
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2016-08-02T23:28:34Z
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2016-08-02T23:28:35Z
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2016-08-02T23:28:34Z
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://1bf65bbec830e32e85e1cd9e22a5db7a2b623c6d9d7da17c747d256a9838676f
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.1.0
    imageID: docker://sha256:d023c050c0651bd96508b874ca1cd628fd0077f8327e1aeec92d22070b331c53
    lastState: {}
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: 2016-08-02T23:28:34Z
  hostIP: 10.178.153.57
  phase: Running
  podIP: 172.16.100.9
  startTime: 2016-08-02T23:28:34Z
```

**API Server config**

```
/opt/bin/kube-apiserver --logtostderr=true --v=0 --etcd-servers=http://internal-etcd-elb-236896596.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:80 --insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0 --secure-port=443 --allow-privileged=true --service-cluster-ip-range=172.20.0.0/16 --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --cloud-provider=aws
```

**API Server is accessible from remote host (laptop)**

```
$ curl http://10.178.153.240:8080/
{
  "paths": [
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    "/apis",
    "/apis/apps",
    "/apis/apps/v1alpha1",
    "/apis/autoscaling",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v1",
    "/apis/batch",
    "/apis/batch/v1",
    "/apis/batch/v2alpha1",
    "/apis/extensions",
    "/apis/extensions/v1beta1",
    "/apis/policy",
    "/apis/policy/v1alpha1",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/logs/",
    "/metrics",
    "/swaggerapi/",
    "/ui/",
    "/version"
  ]
```

**UI is not accessible remotely**

```
$ curl -L http://10.178.153.240:8080/ui
Error: 'dial tcp 172.16.100.9:9090: i/o timeout'
Trying to reach: 'http://172.16.100.9:9090/'
```

**UI is accessible from Minion Node**

```
core@ip-10-178-153-57 ~$ curl -L 172.16.100.9:9090
 <!doctype html> <html ng-app="kubernetesDashboard">...
```

**API Server route tables**

```
core@ip-10-178-153-240 ~ $ ip route show
default via 10.178.153.1 dev eth0  proto dhcp  src 10.178.153.240  metric 1024
10.178.153.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.178.153.240
10.178.153.1 dev eth0  proto dhcp  scope link  src 10.178.153.240  metric 1024
172.16.0.0/12 dev flannel.1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.6.0
172.16.6.0/24 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.6.1
```

**Minion (where pod lives) route table**

```
core@ip-10-178-153-57 ~ $ ip route show
default via 10.178.153.1 dev eth0  proto dhcp  src 10.178.153.57  metric 1024
10.178.153.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.178.153.57
10.178.153.1 dev eth0  proto dhcp  scope link  src 10.178.153.57  metric 1024
172.16.0.0/12 dev flannel.1
172.16.100.0/24 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.100.1
```

**Flannel Logs**
It seems that this one route is misbehaving with Flannel.  I'm getting these errors in the logs but restarting the daemon does not seem to resolve it.

```
...Watch subnets: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured

... L3 miss: 172.16.100.9

... calling NeighSet: 172.16.100.9
```

Comment: This is possibly an issue with the service not defined or created? 

Can you try to paste the output from kubectl describe svc?

Comment: It's definitely up @SantanuDey.  I added the describe call to the OP and it's getting to the 172.16.100.9 endpoint which surfaces the page.

Comment: If you get response from <ip of the service>:9090 that means it is all right. 

You may need to define an additional service of node port type to be able to access it using the node IP or from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who finds their way to this question, I wanted to post the final resolution as it was not a Flannel, Kubernetes, or SkyDNS issue, it was an inadvertent firewall.  As soon as I opened up the firewall on the API server, my Flannel routes were fully functional and I could access the Dashboard (assuming basic auth was enabled on the API Server).

So in the end, user error :)

Comment: What flows did Flannel need to function properly? Thank you!

Comment: I had TCP traffic exposed in the firewall, but not UDP.  Opening up that restriction resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to expose your service outside of the cluster using a service of type NodePort as mentioned in the previous answer, or if you enabled Basic Auth on your API Server you can reach your service using the following URL:

`http://kubernetes_master_address/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/namespace_name/services/service_name`

See: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls

Comment: Thanks Antoine.  I have added a basic auth file, restarted the api-server, and I'm still seeing the `Error: 'dial tcp 172.16.100.9:9090: i/o timeout'
Trying to reach: 'http://172.16.100.9:9090/'` issue.  If i try to curl with the base64 user:pw, I get unauthorized.  I did attempt the NodePort and was also unable to access the underlying container externally.  Is there something in the Proxy that is misconfigured? @antoine-cotten

Comment: That's because you're trying to access your service IP, which is most likely not routable in the network where your workstation is! Try the URL I posted instead (replace `namespace_name` and `service_name`), and make sure you're using your *master* IP / address

Comment: yes, that is what i am doing.  Here is the full URL I am attempting to hit: https://10.178.153.240/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/

Comment: Is your master inside your overlay network? The network used to route the subnets associated to your Docker bridges (Flannel, Weave...)

Comment: yes, the master is inside the overlay.  I am running the flannel daemon on the master but if i try to hit `http://172.16.100.9:9090` from the master, I get a connection timeout.  I am only able to get a successful response when I am on one of the minions/nodes.  So perhaps this is an issue with my overlay?

Comment: Maybe, 172.16.100 is your overlay network apparently. If everything was setup correctly you should be able to curl your Pod IP from the master. You should post the output of `ip route show` on both your master and node(s) in your original question.

Comment: routes added for both the master and minion where the Pod is located.

Comment: The route table looks good, it might be worth checking the Flannel logs, and make sure you're using a backend your system can support. The firewalls might also be too restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

If you try adding another service like in the definition below, then you I think you should be able to access the dashboard using any of the node IP and the nodeport which is in this example 30100

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kube-expose-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30100
      targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

Comment: Correct. It is not necessary to create another service for that though, the NodePort can be added by simply patching the existing Service, for example with `kubectl edit svc kubernetes-dashboard`